# Razor Engine repeat header in PDF

Tags: pdf, razor, pdf-generation

I'm using C# and RazorEngine to generate a PDF from an HTML template.  I'm trying to get a header to repeat on each page.  I've tried multiple things to get it to work, but it doesn't repeat no matter what I try.  Here is one example of what I've tried.

```
<table>
    <thead style="display: table-header-group;"><tr><th>Test THEAD</th></tr></thead>
    @for(var i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
        <tr><td>Test TD </td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

Technically, the header doesn't need to be part of a table.  The template itself isn't one big table, but if I need to, I can wrap it all in a table if that's what I need to do to get the header to repeat.  Any ideas are much appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

As per Richard Morgan's advice, I tried this and it didn't work.

```
<table stlye="page-break-inside:auto;">
<thead style="display:table-header-group; display: table-header-group;">
    <tr stlye="page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;">
        <th>Test THEAD</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@for(var i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
    <tr style="page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto">
        <td>Test TD </td>
    </tr>
}
<tfoot style="display:table-footer-group;">
    <tr>
        <td>TFOOT</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem using htmltopdf and got a nearly workable solution with the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group; display: table-header-group; }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
```

You're already using  so it should be simple to try.

I think it depends on what the PDF generator is using to render the HTML.  I've not used Razor for PDFs so your experience might be different.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.  I'm updating my original post with the exact code.